# ssl and https in nginx using meteor

Tags: ssl, nginx, meteor, meteor-up

I have this nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app.com www.app.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name app.com www.app.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/app.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    root /opt/myapp/app/programs/web.browser/app;
    access_log off;
    expires 1w;
  }

  location ~* "^/[a-z0-9]{40}\.(css|js)$" {
    root /opt/myapp/app/programs/web.browser;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ "^/packages" {
    root /opt/myapp/app/programs/web.browser;
    access_log off;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

and deployed to ec2 using mup with normal settings

It is deployed and i can access the site `app.com`

But the `https://app.com` is not working

as In the config file all the requests are rewriting to `https`
What is happening here

- I can access the site when I enter app.com that means it is
  forwarding app.com ad https://app.com
- I cannot access https://app.com that means nginx is not working

Which of the above two scenarios are true?

I'm out of options. I checked with ssl checkers they are showing that ssl certificate is not installed.

then why my app is working when enter app.com?

Comment: Perhaps you should try Cluster: https://meteorhacks.com/cluster-a-different-kind-of-load-balancer-for-meteor.html . I haven't tried it personally, but Arunoda has done a lot of good work on similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Meteor Up has the built in [SSL Support](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#ssl-support). No more hard work.

Just add the SSL certificates and the key and do `mup setup`.

> We use [stud](https://github.com/bumptech/stud) to terminate SSL

Answer (score 1):

I am not NGINX knowledgeable but looking at my working production configs I see a number of parameters you have not included in yours.

In particular you may need the following at the top in order to proxy websocket connections:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
```

My 443 server also includes the following in addition to what you already have:

```
server {
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Finally I would try commenting out your location directives for bug checking. The issue should not be with your SSL certificate, it should still allow you to visit (with a warning) for a self-signed or misconfigured certificate. Hope this helps.